# Indexing status showing "Computing Ranking" - SP2007

Tags: search, 2007, crawling, status

My SP2007 farm's Central Admin --> Search Settings displays the "Indexing Status" as "Computing Ranking".

Currently there are no Full crawls or Incremental crawls scheduled due to low disk space.

We are planning to move the Index file location to a new location and making "Indexing Status" to "Idle" is a pre-requisite for moving index files to a new location.

How to make the Indexing Status to Idle?

[image]